# inner join with group by function

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am trying to get results matching a variable using a LIKE operator combined with an INNER JOIN and a GROUPING modifier.

The problem I am having with this query:

-the join will not work with the modifier as it is being grouped by the same column that is being used to join the two tables. I get the error '#1052 - Column 'Agency' in field list is ambiguous'

```
SELECT Agency,Acronym,last,sum(last),current,sum(current),source,url
FROM `budget_table` INNER join budget_table2 on 
budget_table.agency=budget_table2.agency WHERE (Agency) LIKE('%$agency%') GROUP BY Agency
```

I have looked through other answers but am not able to apply what is posted to what I am doing. Assistance would be appreciated. Is there something wrong with my JOIN?

I am trying to select only agencies common to both tables and then match data against the variable from within those results.

Comment: you must specify either `budget_table.Agency` or `budget_table2.Agency` (mysql doesn't know which one to choose).

Comment: u have Agency in both tables, so u need to use table alias to refer them.

Comment: thanks for that. I'm trying to make it work with the advice but not sure what I'm doing with aliases.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Could you explain the terms DDL and SQL fiddle please?

Comment: The code is for this page http://infoaus.net/budget/estimated_v_actual.php?agency=housing&submit=Show  I am adding a script to the page that shows results for all agencies. For the results from the tables for both arrays to be correct I need to eliminate from those arrays the agencies that are not common to both tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same column name in two tables, you have to reference the table do you want to get the column value. Write the table name before the column name in your select, where and group.

Example:

```
SELECT budget_table.Agency /* ...your code... */
WHERE budget_table.Agency LIKE ('%$agency%') 
GROUP BY budget_table.Agency
```

Comment: I've tried this but it isn't working. {SELECT Agency AS one, Acronym,last,sum(last),current,sum(current),source,url
FROM `budget_table` INNER join budget_table2 on 
budget_table.one=budget_table2.one WHERE (agency) LIKE('%health%') GROUP BY budget_table2.agency}  I've never used alias before and not finding very good resources on it so

Comment: Apparently your GROUP BY is correct now. (GROUP BY budget_table2.Agency). But you need to do the same in your WHERE and SELECT. Something like this: "SELECT budget_table2.Agency FROM budget_table INNER JOIN budget_table2 on budget_table.one = budget_table2.one WHERE budget_table2.Agency like '%health%' GROUP BY budget_table2.Agency"

Comment: You have to write the alias for the column in tthe WHERE clause as well: `WHERE (budget_table.agency) LIKE...`